# Unable to access a value from applications.properties file in StepExecutionListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

In a spring batch, I'm trying to access a property from `application.properties` file in my `StepExecutionListener`using spring's `@value` annotation, but it turns out to be `null`.

```
@Component
public class SomeListener implements StepExecutionListener {
 
@Value("${some.property}")
private String foo;

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
 
}
```

This piece of code print `null`.

Comment: `SomeListener` does not appear to be a Spring Bean, since it doesn't appear to be annotated with `@Component`. How is the object instance created? Injection only works for Spring-managed beans.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19896870/5221149)

Comment: @Andreas That was my bad, `SomeListener` is a bean annotated with `@Component`. The issue was that it's object was being created using `new` keyword instead of using the `@Autowired` annotation where it was being used in the Job bean. The link was helpful. If you can post this as an answer, so I can accept.